# Set textview value in particular row in listview Android

Tags: android, listview

I have on listview which include four textview.  my view is as below
[image: Current View]

I want to set quantity manually as per particular item with help of dialog value my code is as below

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

    Spinner mSpinnerMeal;

    OrderAdapter mOrderAdpter;
    ArrayList<ParserOrder>mArrayList;
    ListView mListView;
    TextView mTextViewSubmit;
    Dialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.order, container, false);
        mSpinnerMeal=(Spinner)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_spn_meal_type);
        mArrayList=new ArrayList<ParserOrder>();
        StaticValue.noOfFragment=2;
        mDialog=new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar|android.R.style.Theme_Holo|android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mListView=(ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_listview);
        mTextViewSubmit=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_txt_submit);
        mTextViewSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        mOrderAdpter=new OrderAdapter();
        mListView.setAdapter(mOrderAdpter);
        return mView;
    }

    public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        ArrayList<ParserOrder >mList;
        FragmentActivity mActivity;
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public OrderAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            mViewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_order, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewItenam=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_iteamname);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewPrice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_price);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewTotal=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_txt_total);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_edt_qty);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewItenam.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamname());
            mViewHolder.mTextViewPrice.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamprice());
            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setId(position);

            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_qty);
                    final EditText  mEditTextQty=(EditText)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edt);
                    TextView  mTextViewOk=(TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_ok);
                    TextView mTextViewCancel=(TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_cancle);
                    mTextViewOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setText(mEditTextQty.getText().toString().trim());
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    mTextViewCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });

            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setTag(position);
            if (convertView==null) {
                mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.getTag();
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mTextViewItenam;
        TextView mTextViewPrice;
        TextView mTextViewQty;
        TextView mTextViewTotal;
    }
}
```

right now issue is when I run this code and click any quantity textview it will set value at the last of textview only one time when I click again any textview and try to set value in text it is not allow toset that value in any textbox any idea how can I solve this problem?

**Edit Code**

As per your suggestion I make a change my code as below

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

    Spinner mSpinnerMeal;

    OrderAdapter mOrderAdpter;
    ArrayList<ParserOrder>mArrayList;
    ListView mListView;
    TextView mTextViewSubmit;
     Dialog mDialog;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.order, container, false);
        mSpinnerMeal=(Spinner)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_spn_meal_type);
        mArrayList=new ArrayList<ParserOrder>();
        StaticValue.noOfFragment=2;
        mDialog=new Dialog(getActivity(),android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar|android.R.style.Theme_Holo|android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
        mDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mListView=(ListView)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_listview);
        mTextViewSubmit=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.order_txt_submit);
        mTextViewSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });

        mOrderAdpter=new OrderAdapter();
        mListView.setAdapter(mOrderAdpter);
        return mView;
    }

    public class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

        ArrayList<ParserOrder >mList;
        FragmentActivity mActivity;
        ViewHolder mViewHolder;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public OrderAdapter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            mViewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_order, parent, false);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewItenam=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_iteamname);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewPrice=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_price);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewTotal=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_txt_total);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_order_edt_qty);
            mViewHolder.mTextViewItenam.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamname());
            mViewHolder.mTextViewPrice.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamprice());
            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setId(position);

            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_qty);
                    final EditText  mEditTextQty=(EditText)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_edt);
                    final TextView  mTextViewOk=(TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_ok);
                    mTextViewOk.setTag(position);
                    TextView mTextViewCancel=(TextView)mDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_txt_cancle);
                    mTextViewOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int pos=Integer.parseInt(mTextViewOk.getTag().toString());
                            System.out.println("Position  "+pos);

                            mOrder.setIt_id(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIt_id());
                            mOrder.setCid(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getCid());
                            mOrder.setIteamname(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamname());
                            mOrder.setIteamprice(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamprice());
                            mOrder.setSid(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getSid());
                            mOrder.setQty(mEditTextQty.getText().toString().trim());
                            RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.remove(position);
                            RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.add(position,mOrder);
                            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getQty());
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            mOrderAdpter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    mTextViewCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            });

            mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.setTag(position);
            if (convertView==null) {
                mViewHolder.mTextViewQty.getTag();
            }
            return convertView;
        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView mTextViewItenam;
        TextView mTextViewPrice;
        TextView mTextViewQty;
        TextView mTextViewTotal;
    }
}
```

in edited code when I change first time quantity i will work fine but when i change any other item quantity then it is change all other value which  it has any idea how it is occurs? and also how calculate total value for each row and how get grand total value for all item?

Comment: where do you specific data to your ViewHolder? I mean your mList as an ArrayList<ParserOrder> is not used in your code to bind data.

Comment: Why don't you use it inside a list view item click listener?

Comment: @MajidDaeiNejad: i used Application Class and in this i mention Arralylist of Order class so when i come this screenn i already fill all data for list item so no need to bind data into mList because Application class data we can use in whole applciation screen as per our nedeed

Comment: isnt not working? @HarshalKalavadiya

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the datasetChanged for the list view adapter.

- first tag the position to that textview as mTextViewOk.setTag(position);
- Get the position in onClick int pos=Integer.parseInt(mTextViewOk.getTag().toString());
- Get the value ie) the object value from the arraylist.
- Change the value that u need to change.
- Finally use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I am updating my ans

> "right now issue is when i run this code and click any quantity textview it will set value at the last of textview only one time when i click again any textview and try to set value in text it is not allow toset that value in any textbox any idea how can i solve this problem ?"

- The reason behind this is the list view behavior it will keep the elements for a single page ie:) if u have 50 items and can show only 5 items in a single page because of the size of the list view items., the adapter will keep the last element datas ., if u change to inside getView means it will update the last item. so
- U have to set Tag () the position to that text view as i mentioned above.(First Two points)

Comment: That's not needed, he only needs to know the pos of the item clicked and call it inside the adapter. `adapter.get(position).setText...` and then the `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: i think i understood his qn as correct. he need to change the list view item value. but now he is facing that while he is changing the value it is updating the last row for that he has to use setTag() and getTag() to the element he is performing the onclick listener.@RotaryHeart
am i understood the qn as correct ?

Comment: He could use the `setTag()`, but he could also use the position inside the adapter, since the adapter know what is in that position. Example: he clicked the 2 row then the code will do: `myAdapter.get(1).setText("My new text");`

Comment: @RotaryHeart i think u r suggesting as like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19193662/1937802

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean

Comment: @RotaryHeart it is going to return the object of the value at that position(ie: single row has 4 values so this object will hold 4 values). by using setText() how it can change the value from that text view?

Comment: Because he should (and I'm sure he have it) a function inside `RestaurantApplication` to change the text value. He is calling that function here: `mViewHolder.mTextViewItenam.setText(RestaurantApplication.mParserOrder.get(position).getIteamname());`

Comment: @RotaryHeart you will get only the last position that i understood from the above code. you can get the parent view from the list view.get(position) then its text view and can change. but doing inside adapter using datasetchage will give good result i think.

Comment: @RotaryHeart:See My Edit Code Please